# Как в Java массив перевести в формат JSON?

Tags: json, java, массивы

Т.е., нужен аналог `php`-шной функции `json_encode()`.

C корректной обработкой вложенности массивов..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. надо скачать и подключить к проекту либу с [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

2.

Gson gson = new Gson();

```
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Comment: отличненько! это то, что мне было нужно. пример использования также весьма к месту.

Answer (score 3):

На помощь вам придут:

- [json-java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONWriter.java)
- [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
- [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)